# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la ruta de un archivo que cargué con openFileDialog?

Tags: c#

En una carpeta tengo un archivo Excel y varios PDF, esa carpeta puede ser variable dependiendo del usuario. Con un botón uso openFileDialog para subir un archivo .xlsx (En el archivo excel hay una referencia y un nombre PDF). Con otro botón quiero extraer solo la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo .xlsx con el filtro de "*.pdf".

Usando este código: lbl2pdf.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName; Imprima solo la ruta + nombre del archivo.

Espero que puedas ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: No entiendo el problema

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @gbianchi estoy empezando a desarrollar en C# por lo cual con un botón sube un archivo .xlsx con openFileDialog  pero quería saber sí se puede de alguna forma obtener la ruta del archivo y en esa misma ruta buscar archivos pero ahora .pdf

Comment: @gbianchi, gracias

Comment: es winforms? wpf?? en que estas trabajando???

Comment: sí  es en C# winforms